# Jquery fails to call webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to call a webservice http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx using Jquery AJAX.

```
 function AppendListItems() {
            var webMethod = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: webMethod,
                data: { Celsius: "10" },
                success: function (msg) {

                    $("#lstPhoneNames").append("<li>" + msg.d + "</li>");
                },
                error: function (ex, a, b) {
                    alert(b);
                }
            });

        };
```

but, the call fails It returns error log:

```
 <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
            <br><br>

            <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This &lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to &quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;

&lt;configuration&gt;
    &lt;system.web&gt;
        &lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
    &lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

    </body>
```

Am i calling the service wrong way?

Comment: are you testing this on browser or on emulator or on real device?

Comment: yup i am testing this on IE,chrome browsers

Comment: i've never been able to test ajax calls from browsers when using jquery-mobile, somehow they work only in emulator or real device. I'd like to know if someone knows what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try adding on document ready:

```
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

check what the actual request is sent to the server using some tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). You might find differences in what you send, as to what actually is required

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL for webservice Should it be http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit ?? OR

http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=FahrenheitToCelsius ??

Comment: Returned result : Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid.